# Changing time format

Tags: php, datetime

sorry for my English.
I’m trying this:

```
$startTime = strtotime('2013-12-23');
$endTime = strtotime('2013-12-31');

for ($i = $startTime; $i <= $endTime; $i = $i + 86400) {

    echo date('m.d.Y', $i)."<br/>";

    echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime(date('m.d.Y', $i)))."<br />";

}
```

So, why I get:

```
12.23.2013
01-01-1970
12.24.2013
01-01-1970
...
```

If I try

```
echo date('m.d.Y', $i)."<br/>";
echo date('d-m-Y', $i)."<br/>";
```

It’s ok, I get correct result.

Thanks You.

Comment: Why you not just use `echo date('d-m-Y', $i)`? Why converting into the one format and then convert to the other?

Answer (score 4):

The m.d.Y is a format strtotime can not parse. Use another format ( eg 'c' ) to get it working.

This is from the php manual

> Note: Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking
>   at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed. To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601
>   (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Comment: Thanks You, but how I can convert date from m.d.Y to d-m-Y in php 5.2.6

Comment: Why do you want to convert it from m.d.Y? Are you forced to use it? If you really can't work around using another format, use either 
    list($d, $m, $y) = split('.', $dmyString );
or for easy use 
    date_parse($dmyString);

http://nl3.php.net/date_parse

Answer (score 0):

strtotime doesn't take the format 'm.d.Y'

You can see in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) what it does accept.